# GitHub does not let me access Subfolders

Tags: git, zend-framework, version-control, github, git-submodules

**Short:**

GitHub has grayed out folders in my repo that I cannot access.  This worries me, as my code changes are in those folders!

**Long:**

I am developing a ZF2 web application and using git for source control.  ZF2 is modular, so somewhere somehow (most likely with composer.phar or possibly with git clone) I have downloaded some ZF2 modules into project subfolders.  One such ZF2 module is `vendor/coolcsn/csn-user`.  I have made changes in that ZF2 module.

Problem 1:  when I run git status, I get this:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#       modified:   vendor/coolcsn/csn-user (modified content, untracked content)
```

When I run git commit, it says "No changes added to commit".  And I've definitely made some changes.

So then I found that I can change my directory to `vendor/coolcsn/csn-user`, and do git status and git commit there.  Then I can change back to the root directory of the project, and do a git commit there.  Then, all is fine....  until:

Problem 2:  Until I do a git push to GitHub.  On GitHub my entire project seems to be in place, but the `vendor/coolcsn/csn-user` is not accessible on GitHub!  It is Grayed Out.  I cannot click on it.  It makes me cry.  I don't know why and I don't know what's up.  I've read something about git submodules.  I don't know if I have git submodules or if they are something else.  I have not consciously set up any submodules myself.  Either way, I am concerned that my GitHub submodule changes are not being tracked, or if they are being tracked, they are hidden, not accessible for viewing.

Possible Solution #1:  I thought that I could REMOVE .git folder in the submodules (if they are submodules) and just do straight commits to GitHub, with my `csn-user` folder possibly not being grayed out.  But before I do so, I've heard that it is not advisable, and I wanted to check on what all that is going on, and how if anyhow, I can properly use git and GitHub and submodules, and track my changes at the same time.

In particular, looking for a set of steps, instructions, or ideas on how keep my repo accessible and committable both using git and GitHub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be using submodules in your repository. Run `git submodule status` to see the submodules in use.

"Problem 1", your confusion around commits, is due to the difference between committing changes to the root repository vs to a submodule's repository. It sounds like you are committing to a submodule repository and then updating the root repository to point its submodule at that new commit. This may be problematic if you are not publishing those commits because no one else will be able to find them should then checkout the root repository and want to fetch the submodules it depends on.

Github correctly does not show the contents of those directories because they are references to specific commits in other repositories, not part of the root repository itself.

While you could check all of these files into your root repository that does sound dangerous. by doing so you destroy information about where the contents of those subfolders came from. No one else (including you in the future) will be able to easily identify where that content came from or which revision you grabbed from those repositories.

Comment: "...This may be problematic if you are not publishing those commits".  Exactly ... I am in this situation.  I have to edit submodules for my specific business needs, but my changes are not being stored in GitHub.  How do I work this out?  Do I fork the original repositories and then update my links?

Comment: also, I have edited .gitmodules file extensively and added all my submodules into it.

Comment: Yes, if you are making commits to the submodules you want to publish those changes, not necessarily publicly but at least somewhere where anyone building the project can fetch them again (including you if you ever need to switch to a different computer). Switching these submodules to point to your forks of the originals is probably the easiest solution.

Comment: Problem3:  I have private repository, so I cannot fork the public repository as a submodule of my private repo.  I need to copy it as per here:  https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository  So what is so bad about making my submodule `csn-user` in this case just a subfolder of my root repo?  I won't be able to track where things came from, but I will be able to track my own changes to it, and I still will know where the module itself came from.  I am not sure I will be at adisadvantage here.  Is there a stronger case to keep it as submodule?

Comment: The case I'm thinking of is what will you do if useful changes are made to the original `csn-user` repo? Once you strip the repository off of that submodule you may not be able to easily merge upstream changes with your local changes. That may or may not be a concern for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you do have submodule, and running git submodule status to check that out, make sure to:

- *not* run the command from a subfolder of your local Git repository
- or use Git 2.25 (Q1 2020)

That is because, before Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), "[`git submodule`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) `status`" that is run from a subdirectory of the superproject did not work well. That has been corrected.

See [commit 1f3aea2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f3aea22c781d603d56ce794879a8fe8d8dd77d1) (25 Nov 2019) by [Manish Goregaokar (`Manishearth`)](https://github.com/Manishearth).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 88cf809](https://github.com/git/git/commit/88cf80949e0a4c3cacd4be80358e5fe62acbf0ae), 05 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`submodule`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f3aea22c781d603d56ce794879a8fe8d8dd77d1): fix 'submodule status' when called from a subdirectory
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Manish Goregaokar</sup>
>
> When calling `[`git submodule`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) status` while in a subdirectory, we are incorrectly not detecting modified submodules and thus reporting that all of the submodules are unchanged.
>
> This is because the submodule helper is calling `diff-index` with the submodule path assuming the path is relative to the current prefix directory, however the submodule path used is actually relative to the root.
>
> Always pass `NULL` as the `prefix` when running diff-files on the submodule, to make sure the submodule's path is interpreted as relative to the superproject's repository root.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and got resolved by doing the following.

I was trying to synch my local repo to my github repo, but could not due to subfolders having been git initialized by mistake. Once the entries were removed and re-initialed the local state is reflected on my github repo.

1. removed all the `.git` folders from the sub folders as well as from root.
2. `git init`
3. `git add .`
4. `git commit -m "first commit"`
5. `git branch -M master`          (if you are committing from the branch switch to branch)
6. `git remote remove origin`      (if you have any)
7. `git remote add origin https://github.com/abcd1234/xxxxxxx.git`
8. `git push -u origin master`

Comment: Warning: removing the `.git` folders from all the repos will throw away the history from all of the repos. I don't think there's any reason to throw away the root `.git` at all, which would keep the history for the root repository at least. If you also wanted to keep the history from the accidentally-created sub-repositories, you could move them out of the git repo and use `git subtree` to add them back in with history.